# How to remove the webform title field on add/edit form?

Tags: webforms

I am using bartik responsive theme. I made a sub theme of the theme. I enabled the sub theme as the default theme. I have given access to anonymous users to add webform content at xxx.com/node/add/webform. Users see the title field as required. I like to remove the title field of web form so users dont need to enter the title.

I found this link but I could not follow it all the way:

[link](https://www.drupal.org/node/415580).

- "You need to have both node.tpl.php and node-webform.tpl.php in your theme directory for this to work. Also make sure you clear your Drupal caches after copying the files in."

I went to theme directory(theme/xx/templates) and I see bartik, engines, garland, stark, seven. I dont see my sub theme and bartik responsive there. What would be my theme directory in my case?

I simply went to theme/bartik/template> copied node.tpl.php to node-webform.tpl.php and then added

```
<?php if ($page == 0): ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php print $node_url ?>" title="<?php print $title ?>"><?php print $title ?></a></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I still see the web form title field for public users at xxx.com/node/add/webform.

Do you know how I can remove the title field for web form module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind installing another module:

1. Install [Automatic Nodetitles](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle)
2. Go to admin/structure/types/manage/webform/auto_label
3. Select a default title and check "Automatically generate the label and hide the label field"
4. Profit!

Comment: You need both modules, of course! You install this new module just to automagically assign a title to the webform and hide it at the same time

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered but I wanted to also offer a "DIY" alternative (as opposed to installing a module):

Implement `hook_form_alter` in your theme's *template.php* file:

```
function mytheme_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state,$form_id ){
  if ($form_id == 'webform_form_id') {
    // Prevent access to this field.
    $form['submitted']['form_component']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

You will likely also need to set a default value on the field since it is required.

Source: [Programmatically modifying a webform with hook_form_alter()](https://www.drupal.org/node/1558246)